# How to convert .hdr to .pfm with matlab?

Tags: matlab, hdr

Is there a way (or piece of code) that can convert the images that are in .hdr format to .pfm format?

I have a code that reads .pfm files but i want to make it run with .hdr files. 
Converting .hdr files to .pfm on photoshop and reading next unfortunately is not an option.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be great to provide additional information about what .hdr and .pfm files are.  I understand that they are image file formats and I know at one point Matlab supported hdr specific functions in the image processing toolbox.  Have you even looked into that?

Answer (score 1):

The the HDR Toolbox at www.advancedhdrbook.com or https://github.com/banterle/HDR_Toolbox/ has functions for reading and writing both .hdr and .pfm
There is also a high level function for writing and reading HDR Images: hdrimwrite and hdrimread

Comment: Some example usage might be helpful here